# How can I fix the date filter issue on ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a Reports Resource on ActiveAdmin and a date filter.
The problem is I can set the second date field to be prior to the first date field and if I make a search like this, no results show up.How can I fix it?
I have a date column in my db.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a problem.  Although filtering with dates like this isn't useful, as it will always return zero results, it doesn't mean that the search is invalid.

I think this is a case of the designers of ActiveAdmin deciding to make it work in a way that's valid but different to what you expect.